# How to fetch only continuous records from mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table like below

```
___________
id |  speed
-----------
1  |   3
2  |   2
3  |   0
4  |   0
5  |   0
6  |   2
7  |   0
8  |   0
9  |   2
10 |   0
```

Now I want to get the records where speed is 0 but only from 3 to 5 which are continuous and greater than any other continuous records. I don't want 7,8 records or the 10th record. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: By "greater than any other continuous records" do you mean you want the continuous sequence with the largest number of records?

Comment: I think this is known as a 'longest winning streak' problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the fastest method is to use MySQL session variables to increment the "group" each time the speed changes, as you scan through the rows.

```
select n.*, @groupid:=IF(@prev_speed=speed,@groupid,@groupid+1) as groupid, @prev_speed:=speed
from (select @groupid:=0, @prev_speed=-1) _init
cross join n
order by id;

+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
| id | speed | groupid | @prev_speed:=speed |
+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
|  1 |     3 | 1       |                  3 |
|  2 |     2 | 2       |                  2 |
|  3 |     0 | 3       |                  0 |
|  4 |     0 | 3       |                  0 |
|  5 |     0 | 3       |                  0 |
|  6 |     2 | 4       |                  2 |
|  7 |     0 | 5       |                  0 |
|  8 |     0 | 5       |                  0 |
|  9 |     2 | 6       |                  2 |
| 10 |     0 | 7       |                  0 |
+----+-------+---------+--------------------+
```

Then using the above query as a derived table, calculate the lowest and highest id per group, and the count of rows. Sort the groups by the count of rows.

```
select min(id) as minid, max(id) as maxid, count(*) as count
from (
    select n.*, @groupid:=IF(@prev_speed=speed,@groupid,@groupid+1) as groupid, @prev_speed:=speed
    from (select @groupid:=0, @prev_speed=-1) _init
    cross join n
    order by id
) as t1
group by t1.groupid
order by count desc;

+-------+-------+-------+
| minid | maxid | count |
+-------+-------+-------+
|     3 |     5 |     3 |
|     7 |     8 |     2 |
|     1 |     1 |     1 |
|     2 |     2 |     1 |
|     6 |     6 |     1 |
|     9 |     9 |     1 |
|    10 |    10 |     1 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Then using the first row from the above as another derived table, join to the original table for the rows in the range from the min to max id.

```
select n.*
from (
        select min(id) as minid, max(id) as maxid, count(*) as count
        from (
                select n.*, @groupid:=IF(@prev_speed=speed,@groupid,@groupid+1) as groupid, @prev_speed:=speed
                from (select @groupid:=0, @prev_speed=-1) _init
                cross join n
                order by id
        ) as t1
        group by t1.groupid
        order by count desc limit 1
) as t2
inner join n on n.id between t2.minid and t2.maxid

+----+-------+
| id | speed |
+----+-------+
|  3 |     0 |
|  4 |     0 |
|  5 |     0 |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: Note that this solution assumes that there can only be *one* maximum streak.

Comment: @Strawberry, no, it just *returns* one maximum streak. If you have more than one that are tied for the maximum length, you'll get one of them. The OP's requirements were not specific about this type of case.

Comment: @BillKarwin, thank you for the answer. But I solved my problem with if condition (previous and  present and next speeds are zero) by retrieving all the records.